# Can’t load some websites on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have been performing testing to tackle the problem in question so that I can describe as accurate as I can. Let me share with you an overview of the problem first then I'll put the list of tests and the results after.

Some sites suddenly just won't open! Like Yahoo mail (I can open `yahoo.com` though), `support.hostgator.com` (I can open Hostgator still), and Namecheap live chat support page (can open most of the pages on the site), etc. By cannot open I mean I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`, or keeps loading forever.

The following tests are ran on a machine, call it **A**, running Ubuntu 18.04.2.

### Machine A: Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2

- Cannot load any of those buggy pages on Chrome (Version 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)).
- Cleared cache of that site (opened “Developers Tools > Application > Clear Storage > Clear Site Data”) but still cannot open these websites.
- Tried to open the page in incognito window (all extensions disabled). No luck.
- Tried to open in Firefox. No luck.
- Tried to open in Firefox private window. HTML file loaded but no CSS or JavaScript.
- Tried to open in Tor browser. Worked just fine.
- Restarted the router. Ran the same tests above. Same results.
- Changed the wifi network to connect to another hotspot (mobile data). Pages loaded successfully.

### Machine B: Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2

I ran the same tests on another machine, call it **B**, running Ubuntu 18.04.2 (just like A). Same results.

### Machine C: Windows 8.1

I ran the same tests on another machine, call it **C**, running Windows 8.1. Pages are loaded successfully. No need to open in incognito window whatsoever.

### Machine D: Android Phone

A bit of a different behavior here. support pages are loaded successfully. But cannot open Yahoo mail. When I change to mobile data, I can access the Yahoo mail.

Now, what is happening? There is no consistent behavior across all devices!

### Update 1

Performed one more test on machine A. I Curl'd against the Yyahoo mail page and I receive the data successfully. curl worked and chrome didn't?

> `curl -v --request GET --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36' 'https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&.partner=none&.lang=ar-JO&.intl=xa&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com%2Fd%3F.intl%3Dxa%26.lang%3Dar-JO%26.partner%3Dnone%26.src%3Dfp'`

### Update 2

I was able to load the login page in a Firefox regular window, not private. However, I couldn't do much else. Meaning, after supplying the username and hitting next, the request times out.

I copied the curl command from machine A and ran it, and received empty response!

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server.

I altered the request header and removed the cookies part, and I successfully received response!

What does this suggest?

### Update 3

Behavior is becoming more consistent. For some reason, inaccessible pages are inaccessible across all Linux boxes and even Android phone and tablet. Pages are accessible on Chrome running on Windows!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem!

It was changing the MTU of my network module. MTU is the max transmission unit that determines the max size of each packet transmitted on a link from one host to another.

I was using 1500. Changed to 1400. This is how:

```
ifconfig <dev> mtu 1400
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35426610/1051589).

Comment: I have also updated the router's WAN setting to set a lower value of MTU so that any connected device doesn't suffer from the same problem B-)

Comment: Tried `ifconfig <dev> mtu 1400` but it says `bash: dev: No such file or directory` , can you help?

Comment: @mahfujasif, change `<dev>` with the actual device name. Mine was `wlo1`. Type `ifconfig` and you will fine devices with their statuses. The one you want is the one with inet value similar to `192.168.1.x`.

Comment: Yap i found out right away. I should have add the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar looking problem

I couldn't load gitlab.com and very few other sites, on KDE Neon 20.

**Other computers on the same network had no issue opening those same sites.**

**Other network on the computer had had no issue opening those same sites.**

after trying various solutions including the accepted answer nothing was working. then I deleted the wireless network from connection setting (Same as forget network). and then reconnected again and boom its working. now it seamlessly opening gitlab.com and other sites.

I don't know what happened, but **this method worked**.

So first try doing this, as it causes nothing harm.
& I urge the community to shed some light on why deleting the network worked.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Ubuntu 21.04, Gnome 3.38.5.